Coherent topology with subspaces

EXAMPLE 2. Let $ J $ be a discrete space, and let $ E = [0,1] \times J $. Then the quotient space $ X $ obtained from $ E $ by
collapsing the set $ \{0\} \times J $ to a point $ p $ is a linear
graph.
The quotient map $ \pi : E \to X $ is a closed map. For if $ C $ is
closed in $ E $, then  $ \pi^{-1}(\pi(C)) = C \cup (\{0\} \times J )  $ if
$ C $ contains a point of $ \{0\} \times J $, and $\pi^{-1}(\pi(C))=C$
otherwise.  In either case, $ \pi^{-1}(C) $ is closed in $ E $, so
that $ \pi(C) $ is closed in $ X $. It follows that $ \pi $ maps each
space $ [0,1] \times \alpha $ homeomorphically onto its image $
 A_\alpha $, so that $ A_\alpha $ is an arc. The topology of $ X $ is
coherent with the subspaces $ A_\alpha $ because $ \pi $ is a quotient
map.

The above is from Munkres' Topology page 503, can someone fill in the gap from $\pi$ is a quotient map to The topology of $ X $ is
coherent with the subspaces $ A_\alpha $

The topology of $X$ is said to be coherent with the subspaces
$X_\alpha$ provided a subset $C$ of $X$ is closed in $X$ if $C \cap
 X_\alpha$ is closed in $X_\alpha$ for each $α$.


$\pi^{-1}(C)$ doesn't make sense for $C\subseteq E,$ since the codomain of $\pi$ is $X.$ In any event, for $\pi$ to be closed, you need $\pi(C)$ closed in $X$ when $C$ is closed in $E.$ Maybe the book says $\pi(C)$ instead?

You should probably say what this is an example of at the start. You can leave the definition for later, but it is weird to start "Example..." without your readers knowing what it is an example of.

We know that the $p_\alpha : [0,1] \times \{\alpha\} \xrightarrow{p} A_\alpha$ are homeomorphisms.
Let $C \subset X$ have the property that $C \cap A_\alpha$ is closed in $A_\alpha$ for all $\alpha \in J$. Then $p^{-1}(C) = p^{-1}(\bigcup_\alpha C \cap A_\alpha) = \bigcup_\alpha p^{-1}(C \cap A_\alpha)$.
If $p \notin C$, then $p^{-1}(C \cap A_\alpha) = p_\alpha^{-1}(C \cap A_\alpha)$ which is closed in $ [0,1] \times \{\alpha\}$. Since $J$ is discrete, we see that $p^{-1}(C) = \bigcup_\alpha p_\alpha^{-1}(C \cap A_\alpha)$ is closed in $[0,1] \times J$.
If $p \in C$, then $p^{-1}(C \cap A_\alpha) = p_\alpha^{-1}(C \cap A_\alpha) \cup \{0\} \times J$. Thus $p^{-1}(C) = \bigcup_\alpha p_\alpha^{-1}(C \cap A_\alpha) \cup  \{0\} \times J$. As above $\bigcup_\alpha p_\alpha^{-1}(C \cap A_\alpha)$ is closed in$[0,1] \times J$, thus also  $p^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $[0,1] \times J$.
Since $p$ is a quotient map, we conclude that $C$ is closed in $X$.
Update.
Let $Z$ be a topological space and $J$ be discrete. Then $M \subset  Z \times J$ is open (closed) iff all $M \cap (Z \times \{\alpha\})$ are open (closed) in $Z \times \{\alpha\}$. The "only if" is trivial.

Let all $M \cap (Z \times \{\alpha\})$ be open in $Z \times \{\alpha\}$. Since $J$ is discrete, all $Z \times \{\alpha\}$ are open in $Z \times J$. Thus all $M \cap (Z \times \{\alpha\})$ are open in $Z \times J$ and so is their union $\bigcup_\alpha M \cap (Z \times \{\alpha\}) = M$.

Let all $M \cap (Z \times \{\alpha\})$ be closed in $Z \times \{\alpha\}$. Then all $(Z \times J \setminus M) \cap (Z \times \{\alpha\}) = Z \times \{\alpha\} \setminus (M \cap (Z \times \{\alpha\}))$ are open in $Z \times \{\alpha\} $ ansd by 1. $Z \times J \setminus M$ is open in $Z \times J$. Hence $M$ is closed in $Z \times J$.


Therefore, if we are given open (closed) subsets $M_\alpha \subset Z \times \{\alpha\}$, then their union $M = \bigcup_\alpha M_\alpha$ is open (closed) in $Z \times J$.

how we reach from J is discrete to that union being closed?

@DavoodKarimi See my update.
